# Avoiding absolute paths in included cmake files

Tags: cmake

At work, we have a stack built in ROS, with `CMakeLists.txt` files in each package. I'm trying to switch to the `catkin build` tool, which requires that every package be able to build isolated from the others. A file structure looks like:

```
base:
CMakeLists.txt
-- package1:
   [files]
   CMakeLists.txt
-- package2:
   [files]
   CMakeLists.txt
```

The previous build tool (`catkin_make`) started at a root source directory and then adds all discovered `CMakeLists.txt` files as sub-directories. This means that variables set in the base (or further down the line) persist.

The big issue I'm running into is that we have some test config scripts that get loaded and run for each package. You can find them from the base file along the path `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/path/to/file`. For all of the sub-directories, this path still works because `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` is pointed at the root. There are a lot of settings in the root `CMakeLists.txt` like compiler settings and flags, along with configuration information for IDE's and especially the paths to these test files.

When making everything independent, I added `INCLUDE(../CMakeLists.txt)` in each sub-directory to get to this file. However, when I do this, I then also need to change the line in the root `CMakeLists.txt` to be a hard-coded path like so:

```
${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/path/to/file --> ~/hard/coded/path/to/file
```

This is because `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` changes to become the directory of each package, and so I cannot start from there.

Since there are obviously major drawbacks to hardcoding (this doesn't even work on the hardware because the file structure is much different), how can I resolve this? A variable that defined something like `CMAKE_DIR_OF_THE_FILE_WHERE_THIS_LINE_IS` but I doubt that exists. I could also go through and move the test script include lines into each package `CMakeLists.txt` so they are completely independent. I would still get the benefit of all the settings from the root file but then it is on developers to update the test script lines in any packages they work on. But this means if we move/rename the test scripts, then there are many places to fix (which is doable with a big find and replace).

Comment: "A variable that defined something like `CMAKE_DIR_OF_THE_FILE_WHERE_THIS_LINE_IS` but I doubt that exists." - This is known as `CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR` variable. See the duplicate question and its answers for more info.

Comment: This actually does exist, try [`CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR.html).